# SQL Server: convert an int value into a time value

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

In a SQL Server query, I want to convert an int into a time.

The int is representing hours and minutes (hhmm).

For example:

```
1945 --> 19:45
30 --> 00:30
1 --> 00:01
```

This query, after modification with your solution, should return true, true, true.

```
declare @int1 int = 0
declare @int2 int = 35
declare @int3 int = 1810

select 
    @int1 = '00:00', @int2 = '00:35', @int3 = '18:10'
```

Comment: Modulo arithmetic is your friend. So is this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql

Comment: stuff(stuff('0000', 5 - len(@int), len(@int), @int), 3, 0, ':')

Comment: Worth noting that `SELECT @int1 = '00:00'` Won't return TRUE, it would result in a conversion error, due to SQL Server attempting to assign the `varchar` value `'00:00'` to a variable of the data type `int`. To achieve something a TRUE/FALSE response, you'd need to use a `CASE` Expression.

Comment: Is this for a clock (max 23:59) or sum of hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH Times AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1945),(30),(1)) AS V(IntTime))
SELECT IntTime,
       CONVERT(time,STUFF(RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(5),IntTime),4),3,0,':')) As TimeTime
FROM Times;
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @int1 int = 0
declare @int2 int = 35
declare @int3 int = 1805

declare @my_integer_value int

set @my_integer_value = @int1 -- Change to @int2 or @int3 as required.

select convert(char(8),convert
    (DATETIME,cast(@my_integer_value/100 as varchar(2))+':'+cast( @my_integer_value % 100 as varchar(2))+':00'
    ,108),108)
```